# How to focus the camera at a specific object in AR View?

Tags: swiftui, arkit

I have an AR View that is defined like this:

```
struct ARViewContainer1: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var planetSelected: Bool
    @Binding var selectedPlanet: String
    @Binding var cameraAnchor: AnchorEntity?
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
        
        // Set up an AR configuration
        let config = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        config.planeDetection = [.horizontal, .vertical]
        
        // Run the AR session
        arView.session.run(config)
        
        let anchor = try! Solarsystem.loadScene()
        arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
                
        return arView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) {
        // Animate the camera to focus on the selected planet
        if planetSelected {
            // Get the selected planet entity
            guard let anchor = uiView.scene.anchors.first,
                  let planetEntity = anchor.findEntity(named: selectedPlanet) else {
                return
            }
            
            // Move the camera to the selected planet
            let cameraNode = uiView.pointOfView

            let newPosition = planetEntity.position + [-2, 0, 0]
            cameraNode?.move(to: newPosition, relativeTo: planetEntity)
            cameraNode?.look(at: planetEntity.position, from: [-2, 0, 0], relativeTo: nil)
            
            planetSelected = false
        }
    }


}
```

Please note the `updateUIView` function. I am getting this error:

> `Value of type 'ARView' has no member 'pointOfView'`[1] and `'nil' requires a contextual type`[2]

I am getting error 1 on this line `let cameraNode = uiView.pointOfView` and error 2 on this line `cameraNode?.look(at: planetEntity.position, from: [-2, 0, 0], relativeTo: nil)`

Basically what I am trying to do is make the user select a planet, stored in `selectedPlanet` and then the app will find where it is (the planet is moving), and then focus/zoom in on the planet for the user to take a look at :)

Please any help is appreciated.